# Iterate through IList<Hashtable> by index in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am having some trouble iterating through a `IList<Hashtable>`. I am trying to iterate it by index i.e.:

I have an `IList<Hashtable>` with 3 different `Hashtable`s in it. I want to `foreach` each one by `IList`'s index. In example:

I want first to `foreach` all `KeyValuePair`s in `Hashtable` in `IList` index=0. When finished do some stuff and then `foreach` all `KeyValuePair`s in `Hashtable` in `IList` index=1 and so on until all `Hashtable`s are iterated through. Currently the code is as follows:

variable `data` is an `IList<Hashtable>` with 3 `Hashtable`s in it.

```cs
foreach (Hashtable rowData in data[index])
{
    some code here...
}
```

I get the following error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.DictionaryEntry' to type 'System.Collections.Hashtable'.

Comment: Are you really using `Hashtable`, rather than `HashSet<T>`? Anyway, `Hashtable` isn't ordered, and you can't rely on its elements being in any particular order when you iterate through it. I assume that `data` is your array of Hashtables, and so `data[index]` is a single one of those Hashtables? If you iterate through that you'll get `DictionaryEntry`s, rather than yet more `Hashtables`. So you probably wanted `foreach (DictionaryEntry rowData in data[index])`

Comment: the whole tool is created that way, so that is why Hashtable is used. Unfortunately not my choice.

Comment: have you tried this `foreach (DictionaryEntry hti in data[index])                Console.WriteLine($"{hti.Key} => {hti.Value}");`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
foreach(Hashtable rowData in data)
{
    foreach(DictionaryEntry pair in rowData)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{pair.Key} {pair.Value}");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Connell.O'Donnell: Code-only answers, while discouraged, are [still considered answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue). If you don’t find the answer useful without further explanation then the appropriate recourse is to downvote it, not vote for deletion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate through an `IList<HashTable>` via the indexer operator:

```cs
IList<Hashtable> data = new List<Hashtable>
{
    new Hashtable { { "a", "b"} },
    new Hashtable { { "c", "d"}, {"e", "f"} },
    new Hashtable { { "g", "h"} },
};
```

Then you can do the following:

```cs
//Iterate through the IList but interested only about the index
foreach (var index in data.Select((_, idx) => idx))
{
    //Iterate through the Hashtable which contains DictionaryEntry elements
    foreach (DictionaryEntry rowData in data[index])
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{rowData.Key} = {rowData.Value}");
    }
}
```

[Reference for the Hashtable contains DictionaryEntry items.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable?view=net-5.0#remarks)

The output will be either this:

```
a = b
c = d
e = f
g = h
```

or that:

```
a = b
e = f
c = d
g = h
```